# Laravel grouping routes with one name

Tags: php, laravel

i have this below route and that can work correctly

```
Route::get('admin/login', array('as'=>'login', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.login');
}));

app
    views
        back_end
            layouts
                index.blade.php
                main.blade.php
                profile.blade.php
            login.blade.php
```

for admin i have any view for show and i want to grouping that with admin perfix. after this action and use

`http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/login`

`http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/profile`

URL i get this error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

this is my routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('login', function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.login');
    });

    Route::get('index', array('as'=>'dashboard'), function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
    });

    Route::get('profile', function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.profile');
    });
});
```

how to fix this routes. please help me

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue recently. Here is a slimmed down version of the routing that I used, including a catch all. I was routing to controllers, however you can replace that syntax with a function, the rout will be handled the same.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::get('settings','AdminController@settings');
    /* Catch all route */
    Route::any('{all}', function($uri){
        return Redirect::to('admin')
            ->with('flash_error', "The administration page 'admin/$uri' could not be found.");
    })->where('all', '.*');
});
```

As always, make sure to run composer dump-autoload after updating the routes. This worked successfully for me. You will only need the '/' on the relative 'base' route.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes (add a preceding slash `/` to each routes inside the `admin` group) as given below:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/login', function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.login');
    });

    Route::get('/index', array('as'=>'dashboard'), function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.index');
    });

    Route::get('/profile', function()
    {
        return View::make('back_end.layouts.profile');
    });
});
```

It should be `/login` instead of `login` and same for each one.

Comment: not working: ` Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException `

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after made the changes, it should work, I've similar route settings and works fine.

Comment: yes. not any change to run actions.` Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException `